# CK editor Table Tools Toolbar

Tags: ckeditor, toolbar, tabletools

I have a problem with my CK editor, the following addon is installed but does not show in toolbar: http://ckeditor.com/addon/tabletoolstoolbar

[image]

I used builder for create my editor here you can find the config:

```
var CKBUILDER_CONFIG = {
    skin: 'office2013',
    preset: 'full',
    ignore: [
        '.bender',
        'bender.js',
        'bender-err.log',
        'bender-out.log',
        'dev',
        '.DS_Store',
        '.editorconfig',
        '.gitattributes',
        '.gitignore',
        'gruntfile.js',
        '.idea',
        '.jscsrc',
        '.jshintignore',
        '.jshintrc',
        'less',
        '.mailmap',
        'node_modules',
        'package.json',
        'README.md',
        'tests'
    ],
    plugins : {
        'a11yhelp' : 1,
        'about' : 1,
        'autosave' : 1,
        'basicstyles' : 1,
        'bidi' : 1,
        'blockquote' : 1,
        'clipboard' : 1,
        'colorbutton' : 1,
        'colordialog' : 1,
        'contextmenu' : 1,
        'dialogadvtab' : 1,
        'div' : 1,
        'elementspath' : 1,
        'enterkey' : 1,
        'entities' : 1,
        'filebrowser' : 1,
        'find' : 1,
        'flash' : 1,
        'floatingspace' : 1,
        'font' : 1,
        'format' : 1,
        'forms' : 1,
        'horizontalrule' : 1,
        'htmlwriter' : 1,
        'iframe' : 1,
        'image' : 1,
        'imagebrowser' : 1,
        'indentblock' : 1,
        'indentlist' : 1,
        'justify' : 1,
        'language' : 1,
        'link' : 1,
        'list' : 1,
        'liststyle' : 1,
        'magicline' : 1,
        'maximize' : 1,
        'newpage' : 1,
        'pagebreak' : 1,
        'pastefromword' : 1,
        'pastetext' : 1,
        'preview' : 1,
        'print' : 1,
        'removeformat' : 1,
        'resize' : 1,
        'save' : 1,
        'scayt' : 1,
        'selectall' : 1,
        'showblocks' : 1,
        'showborders' : 1,
        'smiley' : 1,
        'sourcearea' : 1,
        'specialchar' : 1,
        'stylescombo' : 1,
        'tab' : 1,
        'table' : 1,
        'tabletools' : 1,
        'tabletoolstoolbar' : 1,
        'templates' : 1,
        'toolbar' : 1,
        'undo' : 1,
        'widget' : 1,
        'wsc' : 1,
        'wysiwygarea' : 1,
        'youtube' : 1
    },
    languages : {
        'en' : 1,
        'hu' : 1
    }
};
```

Can anybody help what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved the plugin does not add to toolbar. Find the toolbarGroups in ckeditor.js and add the following:

```
 name : "tables",
        groups : ["table", "tablerow", "tablecolumn", "tablecell", "tablecellmergesplit"]
```